# Error Installing ffmpeg on CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos, ffmpeg, vps

I'm having trouble installing the ffmpeg on my CentOS 6.8.

Before I settled from [this tutorial](http://idroot.net/tutorials/install-ffmpeg-ffmpeg-php-extension-centos/).

Today can no longer, key links returns a 'Not found' on the island.

```
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt: import read failed (2).
```

I also tried [this tutorial](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) but it still fails.

Can someone help me? I take much of ffmpeg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts to get installed and made an explanatory tutorial on how to install FFmpeg on CentOS!

Link: http://central.lpservidor.org/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=36